# Java JPA, Liberty y Solr, problema al conectar con Solr, no encuentra el archivo property

Tags: java, jpa

Estoy con un Web Service en `Java JPA` con server `Liberty` y `Apache Solr` como indexador de datos. Sin embargo, en el momento que la aplicación necesita conectarse a Solr arroja este error

> **com.ban.cos.solr.SolrConnections:** Error leyendo archivo de configuración: ejb\conf\buscador.properties (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)

El resto del error corresponde a un `NullPointerException` ordinario. Voy explicando como viene esta conexión:

En el servicio al que invoco la conexión hago referencia al archivo SolrConnection

```
QueryResponse response = this.solrConnections.getSolrMov().query(query);
```

En el archivo Solr Connections hago un `@Resource` a un `String` que contendrá la query de conexión

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrServer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Singleton
public class SolrConnections {

private static final Logger LOG = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(SolrConnections.class);

@Resource(lookup = "conf/COS_PROPS_LOCATION")
private String propertiesPath;

private CloudSolrServer solrCas;
private CloudSolrServer solrCon;
private CloudSolrServer solrMov;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    File propsFile = new File(this.propertiesPath);
    try {
        InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(propsFile);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(targetStream);
        this.solrCas = new CloudSolrServer(props.getProperty("bc.solr.zkHost"));
        this.solrCas.setDefaultCollection(props.getProperty("bc.indices.cas"));

        this.solrCon = new CloudSolrServer(props.getProperty("bc.solr.zkHost"));
        this.solrCon.setDefaultCollection(props.getProperty("bc.indices.con"));

        this.solrMov = new CloudSolrServer(props.getProperty("bc.solr.zkHost"));
        this.solrMov.setDefaultCollection(props.getProperty("bc.indices.mov"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        LOG.error("Error leyendo archivo de configuración: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Error leyendo archivo de configuración: {}", e.getMessage());
    }
}

public CloudSolrServer getSolrCas() {
    return this.solrCas;
}

public CloudSolrServer getSolrCon() {
    return this.solrCon;
}

public CloudSolrServer getSolrMov() {
    return this.solrMov;
}
}
```

El `lookup` apunta al servidor de `Liberty` que contiene una entrada `JNDI`, que direcciona al archivo `property`.

```
<jndiEntry id="${conf.cos}" jndiName="conf/COS_PROPS_LOCATION" value="ejb/conf/buscador.properties"/>
```

El `value` corresponde al `PATH` del archivo que estoy buscando, pero ya probé cambiándolo sacándole los subdirectorios y sigue sin encontrarlo.

Alguna idea de este error? Desde ya Muchas gracias.

Comment: Es una ruta relativa, así que dependerá del directorio del trabajo del servidor (normalmente en `/bin`). Puedes sencillamente imprimir el valor de `propsFile.getAbsolutePath()` en un log o por consola a ver qué te saca

Comment: En todo caso si -como parece- hablamos de un proyecto que has heredado y del que no encuentras el archivo de configuración, quizás la solución sea averiguar qué significan esas propiedades para, o bien crear tú el archivo de configuración, o bien pasar las propiedades por JNDI. Y de paso documentarlas un poco más para que el problema no se repita.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolví la solución fue setear el value de jndiEntry a una ruta absoluta.